Too many idle database connections in supabase
I am using some edge-functions where I do some direct postgre database operations in supabase.
So whenever this edge function is called, I do something like this:
const pool = new postgres.Pool(databaseUrl, 2, true);

try {
  await connection.queryObject<UserImageModel>(
    `SELECT ...`
  );
} finally {
  connection.release();
}  

I had around ~40 users using my app at the same time, calling this edge function from time to time. I quickly ran into the remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections error.
My micro supabase project supports 60 direct db-connections (https://supabase.com/docs/guides/platform/compute-and-disk#user-content-fn-1)
I thought that my edge function would only use a db-connection for a very short time until connection.release() is called. But when executing
SELECT
  pg_stat_activity.pid as connection_id,
  ssl,
  datname as database,
  usename as connected_role,
  application_name,
  client_addr as IP,
  query,
  query_start,
  state,
  backend_start
FROM pg_stat_ssl
JOIN pg_stat_activity
ON pg_stat_ssl.pid = pg_stat_activity.pid;

to check the open connections to my database I found that when calling my edge function I have two more open connections afterwards. They have status idle but are not completely closed even when the edge-function is completely finished.
I guess this leads to my direct connections to stack up to reach the limit of 60 open connections quite quick. I just called the edge-function from one instance a few times and had quickly 10 open but idle connections.
Apparently I am doing something wrong in closing these connections. Am I doing something obvious wrong?
Do I have to release the complete pool somehow?

connection.release puts it back into the pool for reuse. It doesn't close the connection. If you want that, use a Client directly, and no pool at all.

Can I close the connections of the pool by hand? Can I execute specific sql-queries with the supabase Client?

Yes, see https://node-postgres.com/apis/pool#poolend (Supabase is just a tiny wrapper IIRC)

@Bergi Do you want to write an answer so I can accept it?
